# My Pacman frog won't eat?

Tags: diet, feeding, frogs, amphibians

I have a Pacman frog, named Kiwi, who is about a year old. When we got her she was eating fine and growing but since August her eating pattern has been on and off. We think this is due to being looked after by relatives who didn't really know what to do even though I gave them care guides and lots of help. They gave her a fluffy which was too big for her and it completely messed up her routine. I tried so hard to get her back onto a routine of eating 3-4 locusts 2 times a week (what she was eating before) but she would only eat 3 a week.

Then in September, she refused to eat so we offered her a pinkie mouse. We would try her on locusts again and again but she wouldn't eat them, so we offered her another pinkie. She ate it straight away this continued till November and then she stopped eating completely. There aren't any exotic vets nearby. We have tried everything: wax worms, Dubia roaches, crickets, different size locusts but she won't eat anything.

She hasn't grown in ages and I'm getting worried. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It sounds like your frog is in estivation**

As you've not provided an image yet or any specific tank information, I'll give an answer with general information on how your tank should be set up:

- Pacman frogs should be kept between 25 - 31 °C (77 - 88
  °F).
- If you have a UVB light it should only be on for 12 hours maximum.
- Ensure your tank is moist as they need this for shedding and can also prolong estivation if their skin is too dry. Humidity should sit around 80 %.
- If your tank is quite clear and open, cover the sides as they're used to being in a tropical environment too much light can stress them out.
- 3 inches of substrate is recommended for juveniles so they feel safe and can burrow.
- Try leaving the live "prey" in the terrarium loose instead of using tongs. The movement may encourage your frog to eat.
- Ensure you're not being overbearing on your frog. Humans can be intimidating for smaller creatures so you may accidentally be stressing your frog out around feeding times.

What concerns me is how long your frog has not been eating for. If making the above changes do not work within a week or two I would remove the frog, pop it into a container with a locust or two. Leave and come back within 10 to 15 minutes.

If that is unsuccessful you're unfortunately going to have to force feed your frog. The easiest thing to do this with is a roach as you can slip the side of the shell into your frogs mouth easier. Once the first roach is in your frogs mouth should stay open for a few seconds and if you're quick enough the next roach should be easier to pop in.

I hope this helps, feel free to pop more information into your question if you'd prefer a more specific answer!

Comment: Thank you for your help.My tank is normally 25 degrees to 28 .She has 4 inches of substrate .she doesnt have a uvb bulb do u think its a good idea to get one?